# C#/Selenium using XPath to find given column cells (nested XPath)

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, datagrid

I am struggling with extracting some data from a datagrid with XPath in Selenium.

I'm getting all the rows to a `IList<IWebElement>` using following XPath: `.//*[@class='datagrid']/tbody/tr`, and supposedly it works.

Now, since I'm interested in extracting only data from some columns (they can be in different order each time but I have it covered, I just run a method to get of the indexes I want from table headers) I just want to run a foreach loop to get cells with given indexes.

I'm trying to do this using relative XPath from the row element.

```
foreach (var tableRowsElement in TableRowsElements)
{
    IWebElement someDataElement =
        tableRowsElement.FindElement(
            By.XPath("//td[currentColumnIndex]")
}
```

Obviously, to minimize code pasted `currentColumnIndex` is a key from a dictionary where I store my "`index, header name`" pairs of columns I want the data to be collected from. The value **is not** hardcoded.

But this code gives me `NullReferenceException`. I tried to modify my XPath but it looks like I don't understand how to make it relative to my tableRowElement.

The DOM of the table looks like a standard one:

```
<table class="datagrid">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <!-- Lots of these, I want to get them-->
        </tr>
           .
           .
           .
        <tr>...</tr> <!-- Even more of these -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried finding the answer in XPath docs but I couldn't find anything about relativity.

Comment: I did not understand what you want to find :( But relative xpath must begin with the point `.//td[currentColumnIndex]` or `./td[currentColumnIndex]` if tds are children of the node

Comment: @splash58 Thanks for your comment. What is the difference then between `.//` and `./`? I want to get `td's` from each row.

Comment: `<table><tbody><tr>` - relative to table `./tbody` and `.//tr` will find. `./tr` - will not find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 changes:

1. you need to use `FindElements` with "s" at the end to get a list of all elements that fit the xpath-query (otherwise you will only get the first hit)
2. you best search relative with ".//" in your xpath expression

   ```
   foreach (var tableRowsElement in TableRowsElements)
   {
       ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> someDataElements =
           tableRowsElement.FindElements(
           By.XPath(".//td[currentColumnIndex]"));
   }
   ```

I hope you will fix the "currentColumnIndex" by yourself, I suppose this is meant to be a variable (which it isn't in your current code)

#### as for the difference of ".//" and "./"

`.//` finds ALL elements below the current element, also children of children etc.

`./` will only find all elements one level below the current element, that is only direct children, not! children of children...

#### Update:

When you still run into `NullPointerException`, the error might be somewhere in your code that you didn't post.

You could try for example to check with a fixed `tr`:

```
".//tr[1]/td"
```

this should return all `td` nodes within the first `tr`-element

Comment: So basically even when I look for one element at a given index (e.g. `.//td[3]`) I have to look for all elements just so it could take the third one? And yes, `currentColumnIndex` is a variable in my code, as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: And secondly, when using `.FindElements` don't I have to use the List or other collection?

Comment: your right, of course you need a List then -> updated my answer

Comment: and no, if you only want ONE element, you don't need FindElements, you can still us .//td[3] -> but since you wrote "<!-- Lots of these, I want to get them-->" I assumed you want to find more than one

Comment: Maybe I'll explain a little more. I'm trying to fetch the data from the whole table, but I do not need all the data. Unfortunately there is no API I could use, so I'm trying to iterate over each row and get the `<td>`'s that I need to store in my model class. I will try out what you posted and see where it takes me.

Comment: yeah, go for it, feel free, to update your question, so we can help you further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89286/discussion-between-asunez-and-drkthng).